# First Data Global Gateway connection error

Tags: php, gateway, firstdata

Anyone know where I can get a PHP wrapper for the First Data Global Gateway? I found a download directly on their website, but I'm not sure it works.

I am constantly getting the following error:

```
"<r_approved>FAILURE<\/r_approved><r_error>Could not connect.<\/r_error>"
```

I have nothing else. All info is being passed correctly. Nothing in the error log. Any ideas??

Comment: "All info is being passed correctly." - how do you know that, if every request errors out?

Comment: I have printed out all of the XML and confirmed it is correct via the documentation. The connection seems to be the issue. I can provide any info you need.

Comment: First Data requires TCP port 1129 to be open. A closed port is often the cause of not being able to connect.

Comment: Port 1129 is open for outgoing connections. Still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 1129 has to be open for both incoming and outgoing. Bi-directional.